# Android Programming execute function at determined time

Tags: android, time, time-management

I am developing a project in Android and I would like to do the following: at a time determined by the user, like 15:40 for example, I would call a function to change the cellphone to silent mode. How can I set it so this function would be called only in this determined time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager` to trigger a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` that can either do your work directly (if it is cheap) or delegate the work to an `IntentService` (if the work is expensive). The "function" would go in the receiver or the service.